# What might cause a featured image not to display?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I'm writing a child theme for the editr theme and the featured image is not displaying for a new post. The featured images do display for demo content. For the new post, the following markup is rendered:

```
<div class="featured" data-img_bg="">
        <img src="" alt="" style="display: block;">
    </div>
```

The relevant section of the template is:

```
<?php if ( ( $show_thumb || $show_thumb == '' ) && has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

    <div class="featured" data-img_bg="<?php echo $image; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="">
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

This is on a local vagrant VM running Ubuntu 14.04, nginx, php 5.6.

I have checked 'Display featured thumbnail?' and 'Featured post?' in the post editor. At the top of the template, I find that the value of $image is empty:

```
<?php
$show_thumb = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'aq_show_thumbnail', TRUE);

$thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
echo 'thumb value is set to'.$thumb;
$image = aq_resize( $thumb, 1000, 400, true );
echo 'image value is set to'.$image;
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Stepping through using xdebug shows that the aq_resize function is failing at the following code:

else {

```
$editor = wp_get_image_editor($img_path);

if ( is_wp_error( $editor ) || is_wp_error( $editor->resize( $width, $height, $crop ) ) )
    return false;

$resized_file = $editor->save();

if(!is_wp_error($resized_file)) {
    $resized_rel_path = str_replace( $upload_dir, '', $resized_file['path']);
    $img_url = $upload_url . $resized_rel_path;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

`$editor` is set to 'No editor could be selected.'

Comment: Make sure you run the code inside the loop. Check the value of `$thumb`, `get_post_thumbnail_id()` etc..

Comment: @Sisir thanks. the value of thumb is the path to the image.

Answer (score 1):

The php extension PHP GD was not installed on my dev machine. Installing php5-gd resolved this - `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`

Stepping through using xdebug revealed that the theme's `aq_resize` function was failing at the following code:

```
else {

    $editor = wp_get_image_editor($img_path);

    if ( is_wp_error( $editor ) || is_wp_error( $editor->resize( $width, $height, $crop ) ) )
        return false;

    $resized_file = $editor->save();

    if(!is_wp_error($resized_file)) {
        $resized_rel_path = str_replace( $upload_dir, '', $resized_file['path']);
        $img_url = $upload_url . $resized_rel_path;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

`$editor` was set to 'No editor could be selected.'

Answer (score 0):

Is the html output to the page?
If not, then the issue is almost certainly with your if statement.
Should it be:

```
if ( ( $show_thumb || $show_thumb !== '' ) && has_post_thumbnail() )
```

instead of:

```
if ( ( $show_thumb || $show_thumb == '' ) && has_post_thumbnail() )
```

Comment: yes the markup is outputted. Its just the value of $image that is empty.